# !empty() for array key brings up values with "0" and NULL

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with keys and values. The Keys are always set, the values might be "0" or NULL. What I want to do: Add all key-value-pairs which have a value into a new array. I use `!empty()` for this.
Problem is: This loop also adds keys to the new array which contain NULL or "0".

Here is my code:

```
    // Loop over array and find all vars which are not empty
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($allInfoArray as $aKey=>$aVal) {
        if (!empty($aKey[$i])) {
            $relevantInfoArray[$aKey] = $aVal;
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

After that I uses `var_dump()` to check the new array.

```
array(11) { ["Key1"]=> string(3) "yes" ["Key2"]=> string(4) "1010" ["Key3"]=> string(4) "DED1" ["Key4"]=> string(7) "1234567" ["Group"]=> string(0) "" ["Dim"]=> string(0) "" ["Grd"]=> string(0) "" ["Nrm"]=> string(0) "" ["Flmc"]=> NULL ["Trmc"]=> NULL ["TrDim"]=> string(0) "" }
```

As you can see, the last values are all 0 or NULL. This also seems to happen randomly, other keys which have the value NULL or 0 are not added to this array.

Any ideas why these keys are added to the new array? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Jeff I thought so too, but it really seemed like a lot fewer values would have ended up in the result.

Comment: You should have checked for `$aVal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't answer why it isn't working, but it looks like you should be able to just use array_filter for this.

```
$relevantInfoArray = array_filter($allInfoArray);
```